# Passing JS variable from child Iframe to parent JSP on cross sub domain

Tags: javascript, localhost, parent-child

I am stuck at 1 location and need some help. I created two subdomains on apache tomcat server like domain1.localhost.com and domain2.localhost.com in server.xml. On domain1 I have a JSP that includes iFrame (hosted on domain2). How can we pass the JS variable from child Iframe to parent JSP and store it in local variable of JSP hosted on domain1.localhost.com?

I tried defining document.domain = "localhost" on both JSP but didn't work. Even parent DOM window is also not available in child iFrame (on sub-domain) because of obvious cross domain policies.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What the exact domain name structure you are using? 
If you are using mydomain.localhost, you are unable to use .localhost as a shared part of domain name, since it is 1st level doman.
If you are using mydomain.localhost.com , then shared part (document.domain) should be "localhost.com" , not just "localhost" as you mentioned in your question.
document.domain should work fine for that purpose, but even if you have two different domains, like company1.com and company2.com it is still possible to pass values from iframe to parent with help of [EasyXDM](http://easyxdm.net/wp/) .

Comment: But I have 1 more problem. I have to assign in parent JS variable the value of child Iframe JS variable. Can you help?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I have missed your second question. So it is better late than never, right?
> I have to assign in parent JS variable the value of child Iframe JS variable.
If they have shared document.domain , then it is easy as `parent.window.someVariableOfParent = someVariableOfIframeChild;`

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, but I do not think this is possible. But maybe you could explain what you are trying to achieve and maybe we could come up with some alternatives :-)

Comment: In child Iframe I have few omniture tags present. I want to pass all those tags to the parent JSP (which is on another domain). So in child Iframe I created a javascript function that takes all omniture tags and create a kind of hash map or key value pair kind of structure and store everything in a variable. Now I need to pass that variable to a local variable of parent JSP so that I can have the omniture tags available at parent level.

Comment: top is the variable you reference to reach the outer frame. It is the window of the outer frame.

So top.document.body is the body of the outer frame. You can call global functions with top.myfunction(sendLocalVariables);

I guess this is the last piece of the puzzle if the cross origin stuff worked :-)